I want to compile Kvantum on my Debian 12 machine
I want to complie kvantum on my debian 12 machine with kde. But I can't install the following dependecy: libkf6windowsystem-dev.
When I run the command sudo apt install libkf6windowsystem-dev I get the following error:
➜  ~ sudo apt install libkf6windowsystem-dev                                                    1249ms  Tue Jun 18 11:35:48 2024
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libkf6windowsystem-dev : Depends: libkf6windowsystem6 (= 6.3.0-1) but it is not going to be installed
                          Depends: qt6-base-dev (>= 6.5.0+dfsg~) but 6.4.2+dfsg-10 is to be installed
                          Depends: qt6-declarative-dev (>= 6.5.0+dfsg~) but 6.4.2+dfsg-1 is to be installed
                          Depends: qt6-wayland-dev (>= 6.5.0~) but 6.4.2-1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

but I am not able to install the 6.5 or higher version of these dependecys since 6.4.2. is the newest version according to apt

Have you asked kvantum developpers?
